# Android Weather Forecast -Error

Tags: android, google-api, google-weather-api

I have done weather forecast using this link

http://www.anddev.org/android_weather_forecast_-_google_weather_api_-_full_source-t361.html.

I got following error :

```
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.anddev.android.weatherforecast/org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.WeatherForecast}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.views.SingleWeatherInfoView
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.views.SingleWeatherInfoView
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:508)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.WeatherForecast.onCreate(WeatherForecast.java:36)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     ... 11 more
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: SingleWeatherInfoView(Context,AttributeSet)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:643)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:472)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:480)
08-09 10:57:45.737: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(539):     ... 21 more
```

This is my Xml File main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/weather_background"
   >
    <TableLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0"
        >
        <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView  
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Usage like: 'City, Country'"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        />
                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/chk_usecelsius"  
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Use °C (not °F)"
                                android:gravity="right"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0"
        >
        <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_input"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Schriesheim, Germany"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        />
                <Button android:id="@+id/cmd_submit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="OK"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.views.SingleWeatherInfoView
        android:id="@+id/weather_today"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="15px"
        />
    <TableLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
        android:paddingTop="15px"
        >
                <TableRow
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.views.SingleWeatherInfoView
                                android:id="@+id/weather_1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                />
                        <org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.views.SingleWeatherInfoView
                                android:id="@+id/weather_2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                />
                        <org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.views.SingleWeatherInfoView
                                android:id="@+id/weather_3"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                />
                        <org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.views.SingleWeatherInfoView
                                android:id="@+id/weather_4"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                />
                        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

and this is my  class file

```
public class SingleWeatherInfoView extends LinearLayout {


    private ImageView myWeatherImageView = null;
    private TextView myTempTextView = null;

    public SingleWeatherInfoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SingleWeatherInfoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
             Map inflateParams) {


        super(context, attrs);
        /* Setup the ImageView that will show weather-icon. */
        this.myWeatherImageView = new ImageView(context);
        this.myWeatherImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.dunno));

        /* Setup the textView that will show the temperature. */
        this.myTempTextView = new TextView(context);
        this.myTempTextView.setText("? °C");
        this.myTempTextView.setTextSize(16);
        this.myTempTextView.setTypeface(Typeface
                .create("Tahoma", Typeface.BOLD));

        /* Add child views to this object. */
        this.addView(this.myWeatherImageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        this.addView(this.myTempTextView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }


    public void reset() {
        this.myWeatherImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.dunno));
        this.myTempTextView.setText("? °C");
    }

    /** Sets the Child-ImageView of this to the URL passed. */
    public void setRemoteImage(URL aURL) {
        try {
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
            this.myWeatherImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            /* Reset to 'Dunno' on any error. */
            this.myWeatherImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.dunno));
        }
    }

    public void setTempCelcius(int aTemp) {
        this.myTempTextView.setText("" + aTemp + " °C");
    }

    public void setTempFahrenheit(int aTemp) {
        this.myTempTextView.setText("" + aTemp + " °F");
    }

    public void setTempFahrenheitMinMax(int aMinTemp, int aMaxTemp) {
        this.myTempTextView.setText("" + aMinTemp + "/" + aMaxTemp + " °F");
    }

    public void setTempCelciusMinMax(int aMinTemp, int aMaxTemp) {
        this.myTempTextView.setText("" + aMinTemp + "/" + aMaxTemp + " °C");
    }

    public void setTempString(String aTempString) {
        this.myTempTextView.setText(aTempString);
    }
}
```

What causes these errors?

Comment: why are you suing "this" key word every where. Are you sure you can add views to this class..

Answer (score 0):

1. Just move all the logic after Setup ImageView... into a new method init(...) and call it from where you moved the logic.
2. Create 
   public SingleWeatherInfoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context, attrs);
     init(...);
   }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the SingleWeatherInfoView class you are using doesn't properly support XML inflation.  You should try creating instances of it from code instead of XML and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the error I was making was putting an incorrect address for the package **SingleWeatherInfoView** in **main.xml**:

```
com.beach.alpha.SingleWeatherInfoView
```

Be sure that your project has this path.